# How to change the class names in the legend of `plotroc`?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm plotting the results of a multiclass classifier using [`plotroc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotroc.html). The documentation is a bit spotty. I'd like to know how to change the automatically generated legend to my class labels.

I have 17 classes. My initial call to `plotroc(target, output)` produces this figure

[image: ROC Curve]

I tried to update the legend to include my class labels using `legend(class_labels)` where `class_labels` is a 17x1 cell array with the labels. Here's the result

[image: ROC Curve with Class Labels]

As you can see multiple labels were assigned to the grey line rather than simply replacing the labels in the first figure.

As an alternative, the documentation also suggests using the syntax `plotroc(targets1,outputs2,'name1',...)` to generate multiple plots, I assume one for each class with different thresholds. So I tried both

```
plotroc(target, output, class_labels)
```

Which returned an error

> Error using horzcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not
>   consistent.
>
> Error in plotroc>update_plot (line 318)
>               titleStr = [names{i} ' ROC'];
>
> Error in plotroc (line 111)
>         plotData = update_plot(param,fig,plotData,update_args{:});

And

```
plotroc(target, output, 'AtLocation', 'IsA', ... 'SymbolOf')
```

Which also returned an error

> Error using plotroc (line 106) Incorrect number of input arguments.

Has anyone had success using the `plotroc(targets1,outputs2,'name1',...)` syntax or with changing the legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a solution using the `plotroc` function directly, but the results from the [`roc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/roc.html) function can be plotted using [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html?searchHighlight=plot) allowing for more customization via the standard Matlab plotting options.

```
function myplotroc(target, output, class_labels)
    [tpr,fpr,~] = roc(targets,outputs)
    figure();
    hold on;
    set(gca, 'LineStyleOrder', {'-', ':', '--', '-.'}); % different line styles
    for ii=1:length(class_labels)
        plot(fpr{ii}, tpr{ii})
    end
    legend(class_labels);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two lines like this (supposing there are 4 ROC curves for the legends of W, L, D, and R respectively):

```
axisdata = get(gca,'userdata');
legend(axisdata.lines,'W', 'L', 'D', 'R')
```